# Submit form in bootbox dialog that was dynamically loaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootbox

I'm using [Bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com/) Dialog to load a php page in the following manner:

```
$('.create_special').on('click', function(event) {
    var loadurl = $(this).attr('data-load-url');
    var title = $(this).attr('data-title');
    $.get(loadurl, function(data) {
        bootbox.dialog({
            message: data,
            title: title,
            buttons: {
                cancel: {
                    label: "Cancel",
                    className: "btn-default",
                },
                submit: {
                    label: "Submit",
                    className: "btn-primary",
                    callback: function() {
                        console.log($(this).closest("form"));
                        $(this).closest("form").submit();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

via:

```
<td><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-load-url="framework/helpers/send_email.php?id=<?php echo $user['user_id']; ?>" class="create_special" data-title="Send Email to <?php echo htmlentities($user['username']); ?>"><?php echo htmlentities($user['email']); ?></a></td>
```

As you can see, I want to be able to have two buttons at the bottom of the modal. One to cancel and close, and one to submit the form in the php file that the dialog loaded. I am having trouble figuring this out, and don't really know where to go from here. As the dialog is getting loaded afer DOM ? I am trying to avoid having to specifically submit the form as I will use this function for other php files with different form names. So it would be nice if I could do something as simple as `this closest`...etc.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm getting what the error is. I assume your form isn't submitting? Is `$(this).closest("form")` supposed to be a form that was loaded by `data`?